Powershell : Scheduled task not running, error 0x800710E0 and id event 153
I create a sheduled task with a powershell script :
$DateTS = (Get-Date).adddays(1).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')

Invoke-Command -Credential $CREDS -ComputerName $PC.DNSHostName -UseSSL -ScriptBlock {
param($DateTS, $ADMIN, $PC)
$Actions = (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "net" -Argument "user $ADMIN /delete")
$Trigger1 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -daily -At $DateTS
$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "SYSTEM" -RunLevel Highest
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Actions -Principal $Principal -Trigger $Trigger1
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Disable" -TaskPath \Microsoft\Windows\BitLocker -InputObject $Task
} -ArgumentList ($DateTS, $ADMIN, $PC)
}

Scheduled task shall be launched one day after creation or day after if Pc is off. But TS never launched. I get error 0x800710E0 adn id event 153 (Task Scheduler did not launch task "\xxx" as it missed its schedule. Consider using the configuration option to start the task when available, if schedule is missed."
Can you help me? Regards. Alex.
EDIT :
Strange, on a VM, i get the issue but on my physical computer, it works.
